# Restangular not working

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm reopening my project that I worked on last week, every thing worked great then, now I can't get anything working, so I have the following service:

```
function userService($log, userModel, Restangular) {
    var service = Restangular.all("user");

    Restangular.extendModel("user", function (data) {
        $log.debug('extend', data);
        return userModel.create(data);
    });
    return service;
}
angular.module("app.services").service("userService", userService);
```

and in another service i have the following method:

```
var isLoggedIn = function(){
    var def = $q.defer();
    userService.one('me').get().then(function(data) {
        if (!data || data === ""){
            def.reject();
        } else{
            $rootScope.user = data;
            def.resolve(data);
        }
    }, def.reject);
    return def.promise;
};
```

so you would think that the the `$log.debug()` get's called upon running the `isLoggedIn()` function, but nope, and the data is empty that get's returned to the `one('me').get()...` function

When I look at the network tab in chorme, I see a correct api call being made to the user/me route

so Any Idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on plnkr.co or a similar site? What response are you seeing in the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

It was a fault in my `addResponseInterceptor` that didn't return the correct data, my bad!